# Won't making Ether more deflationary, make it less useful?

Tags: gas

Won't deflation simply make the network more expensive to use, for any new arrivals who aren't already sitting on deflationary gains?

If there is deflation in Ether and at the same time transaction costs can go down, how does that work?